# Can't type password in log in screen after installing lightdm. Switched to Xorg from Wayland

Tags: boot, login, xorg, lightdm, wayland

I had some trouble running team-viewer, so I followed this [advice](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Linux/Ubuntu-17-10-black-screen/m-p/16424#M687). I installed lightdm

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

and changed the setting to 'lightdm'-Xorg. Previously it was Wayland I believe.

Then, since the problem with Teamviewer wasn't solved, I restarted my computer to see if this will help. Unfortunately, the login screen changed and I cannot type anything in the password box now. The on-screen keyboard doesn't show either. The mouse works. The log in screen looks like this:

[link][1]

I have 2 partitions installed on my machine, one for windows and one for Ubuntu. When booting up my computer I'm only able to access the grub by pressing ctr-alt-f1. After I select Ubuntu to boot I cannot do anything.

Please help! I am under time pressure and any hints or advice to improve the question will be helpful!

### EDIT

I managed to access grub menu and also recovery mode. There I think I will be able to access root but for some reason I don't have the password. Is there anything I can do to switch back to Wayland. Or alternatively can I boot from grub skipping the greeter completely?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNfut.png

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Which release of Ubuntu is this? From the image it looks like it says 13.04, but I'm wondering if that's a display artifact or a problem with the screenshot. (If it is 13.04, that hasn't been supported for a very long time.) I recommend that you **[edit]** this question to include that information.

Comment: Thanks! I will edit it as soon as I get back to the laptop. It is a modern version, the photo I took from internet.